# when service is started, Arraylist in adater is reseted

Tags: android, service

i'm trying to make service copy texts in clipboard when user copy something.
i add object in activity to adater that is used for recyclerview. problem happened when service is started to add other objects in service to adater. before start service, size of Arraylist is 3 but later it turns to '0'...what makes the size of list(the arraylist) zero??

````
    public class WebPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    webadapter adapter2=new webadapter();
    Button buttonB,buttonF,buttonH,buttonM;
    WebView webView;
    EditText editText;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_page);
    RecyclerView recyclerView2=findViewById(R.id.recyclerview2);
            for(int po = 0; po<3; po++) {
                    adapter2.plusitem(new data("sentences", po));
                    adapter2.notifyItemInserted(po);
                    Log.i("info",adapter2.list.size()+"");

            }

                Log.i("info",adapter2.list.size()+"A");
                startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),clipservice.class));
      }
    }
    ```
    ```
    public class clipservice extends Service {
        webadapter adapter2=new webadapter();
        ClipboardManager clipboardManager;
        int sm=Mainpage.temporary.size();
        IBinder B;
        public clipservice() {
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            clipboardManager=(ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            clipboardManager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
                    ClipData clip = clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip();
                    ClipData.Item item = clip.getItemAt(0);
                    String stringitem= item.toString();
                    if(sm<20) {
                        Mainpage.temporary.add(sm, stringitem);
                    }

                    if(sm>=20){
                        sm=0;
                    }
                    if(sm<3){
                        adapter2.setitem(new data(stringitem, sm));
                        adapter2.notifyItemChanged(sm);
                    }else if(sm>=3){
                        adapter2.plusitem(new data(stringitem, sm));
                        adapter2.notifyItemInserted(sm);
                    }
                    sm++;
                }
            });
            Log.i("info","service");
            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            Log.i("info","finish");
        }
    }
````

```
public class webadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<webadapter.ViewHolder>  {
static int T=0;
ArrayList<data> list =new ArrayList<data>();

 public ArrayList<data> setitem(data s){
        Log.i("info",list.size()+"");
        list.set(s.getNumber(),s);
        return list;
    }
}
```

```
I/info: 1
I/info: 2
I/info: 3
I/info: 3A
I/info: service
I/info: 0  <-like this...
```

Comment: plz look a the updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

You are creating a new adapter in the Service. Thats why your arraylist is zero when the service starts.

Instead of updating recyclerview directly from service using adapter, you should create a communication between service and activity.

**An example to Communicate between Service and Activity via BroadcastReciever**

Add following dependency in your build.gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'
```

Add following method in your Service

```
 private  void sendMessageToActivity(String msg) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("Clipdata");
        intent.putExtra("value", msg);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

In your onPrimaryClickChanged()

Replace

```
adapter2.setitem(new data(stringitem, sm));
adapter2.notifyItemChanged(sm);
```

With

```
sendMessageToActivity(sm);
```

Now add broadcast receiver in your activity.

```
  private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String message = intent.getStringExtra("value");
          //HERE ADD VALUE TO THE LISTARRAY and then ADAPTER.NOTIFYDATASETCHANGED
        }
    };
```

In onCreate of activity, Register the Receiver

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("Clipdata"));
```

Dont forget to unregister the receiver on onPause() in Activity

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
    }
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot! by the way i hope to know what unregistering the receiver means..

Comment: Service will keep sending data to your receiver and receiver updates the activity when it has new data..So,If you dont unregister while leaving the activity, you will get a crash because there is no activity now to receive the data from receiver.